# Examples of thread safe classes in the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, locking

I'm currently working on code which is supposed to be thread safe. Lots of asynchronous calls and events and stuff that generally requires quite a bit of work to keep synchronized and thread safe.

Are there any classes in the .NET framework which deal with this sort of thing, which I could look at (decompile), to see how things are supposed to be done? The more complex the better really...

Comment: Use a lock whenever more than one thread can access a shared resource at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has some good information on asynchronous programming in .NET. Check out [Asynchronous Programming Design Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx).

Also check out the [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) and [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) classes in System.Threading

Comment: I am very familiar with both of those classes. Just looking for examples of their use in the .NET framework.

Comment: @NoPyGod: Fire up Reflector or similar, and search what classes within the .net framework use Monitor and Mutex.

Answer (score 6):

[.NET 4.0 Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)

Though targeting Windows rather than just .NET, Joe Duffy's book is worth noting: [Concurrent Programming on Windows](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/books/winconc/winconc_book_resources.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the thread safety here is pretty weak.

Comment: @NoPyGod: erm, say what? There aren't degrees of thread safety. Code is either thread safe or it is not. Your question explicitly asks for "Examples of thread safe classes in the .NET Framework?"

Comment: @Mitch "The wrapper works by locking the entire collection on every add or remove operation. Therefore, each thread that is attempting to access the collection must wait for its turn to take the one lock. This is not scalable and can cause significant performance degradation for large collections. Also, the design is not completely protected from race conditions. "... queuing access to a single object with a single lock is a pretty basic concept. Looking for more complex examples.

Comment: @NoPyGod - If your thread safety skills are so much better than Microsoft engineers, don't ask for examples of their work.

Comment: @John Arlen The first thing I learned about the Monitor class is that you can use it to queue access to an object. It's not a difficult concept to understand. And while I can see that for a collection class that this may be sufficient, the Microsoft developers have said themselves that locking at the collection level is typically not a good design choice, as it should be done at a higher level and within locks that are shared with other data. As my original question states (perhaps not explicitly enough) I am looking for complex examples of thread safety.

Comment: @Mitch I should've said "this particular example of thread safety is pretty weak". I'm completely aware that code is either thread safe or it is not, but there are varying levels of complexity in thread safe applications, and I wish to see code a little more complex than this.

Comment: @NoPyGod: You're looking at the .NET 1.0 collections; the newer .NET 4.0 classes mentioned are much better. @Mitch: You can have incomplete thread safety. The `Hashtable` class, for example, allows multiple readers with one concurrent writer, but not multiple concurrent writers.

Comment: @Gabe: That's a slightly different situation (with certain constraints), but I take your point

Comment: @NoPyGod: You completely missed the real content of the article! It starts with a discussion of the *old* approach to synchronizing collections from .NET 1.0 (this is the section you quoted in your comment). It then goes on to describe the new concurrent collections introduced in .NET 4.0, which are lock-free, highly scalable, and, I assure you, quite advanced.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to keep things atomic.  There are classes that support fencing, such that code is guaranteed to execute in a certain order.  You can use the keyword volatile to ensure that variable access is atomic (Read from memory each use) and that you have no phantom reads.  These are just a few tools;  I would suggest a simple Google of "atomic C#, F#.."

Comment: Very much familiar with locks, mutexes, semaphores etc.. Just looking for strong examples of these things being put to use in the .NET framework.